# Col-auto with img-fluid in bootstrap 4

Tags: image, bootstrap-4, responsive, col

How to use img-fluid if you are using "col-auto"?

My images "turn off" the img-fluid and just make them 100% period. I want my images to be able to still be responsive.

For instance if my images are 1000px each and I have two beside each other in col-autos then they end up bumping down the second one instead of making the images responsive. Is there a way around this?

Images are just placeholders - they do not need to display that size

code below:

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown full-width-nav-dropdown" id="article-ad">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Code Pen
        </a>
        <div class="underline underline-what-we-offer"></div>
        <div class="dropdown-menu top-99 full-width-nav-dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <div class="row px-0 mx-0">
            <div class="col-lg-auto px-0">
              <a class="dropdown-item inside-nav-hovers" href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item inside-nav-hovers" href="#">consectetur adipiscing</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item inside-nav-hovers" href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item inside-nav-hovers" href="#">exercitation ullamco</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item inside-nav-hovers" href="#">Econsectetur adipiscing</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item inside-nav-hovers" href="#">exercitation ullamco</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item inside-nav-hovers" href="#">cillum dolore</a>
            </div> 
            <div class="col-lg-auto px-0 mx-0 article-section d-none d-lg-block">
              <img class="img-fluid pr-3" src="//via.placeholder.com/1000x400">
              <span>commodo consequat capado</span>
              <p class="pr-2">Minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure.</p>
              <a href="#">Read more <i class="fas fa-caret-right"></i></a>
            </div> 
            <div class="col-lg-auto px-0 mx-0 d-none d-lg-block">
             <img class="img-fluid max-100" src="//via.placeholder.com/2000x950">
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </li>
```

Comment: posted code in original question. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're images disappear is due to the `d-none` class

- which means that images will be hidden for all sizes
- the reason you do see images in sizes `lg` and above is due to the class 'd-lg-block'
- in the snippet below, I only removed `d-none`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<li class="nav-item dropdown full-width-nav-dropdown" id="article-ad">
  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Code Pen
        </a>
  <div class="underline underline-what-we-offer"></div>
  <div class="dropdown-menu top-99 full-width-nav-dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
    <div class="row px-0 mx-0">
      <div class="col-lg-auto px-0">
        <a class="dropdown-item inside-nav-hovers" href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item inside-nav-hovers" href="#">consectetur adipiscing</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item inside-nav-hovers" href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item inside-nav-hovers" href="#">exercitation ullamco</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item inside-nav-hovers" href="#">Econsectetur adipiscing</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item inside-nav-hovers" href="#">exercitation ullamco</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item inside-nav-hovers" href="#">cillum dolore</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-auto px-0 mx-0 article-section  d-lg-block">
        <img class="img-fluid pr-3" src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x400">
        <span>commodo consequat capado</span>
        <p class="pr-2">Minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure.</p>
        <a href="#">Read more <i class="fas fa-caret-right"></i></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-auto px-0 mx-0  d-lg-block">
        <img class="img-fluid max-100" src="//via.placeholder.com/2000x400">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```